# How to check if the words from voice search are contained in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, transcription, voice-control

I'm a newbie in learning JS and have been stuck for five days now trying to solve this problem.
I want to be able to play the song that  in its title includes  the words said by User with Voice search .
For now I have response 'Playing ... song', but only if I say the name of the first song, for the other two it doesn't work.

```
// Response
function playingChoosenSong(message) {
  const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

  speech.text = "I didn't catch that, can you repeat?";

  const contains = songs.some((element) => {
    if (message.includes(element)) {
      speech.text = `Playing ${element}`;
      loadSong(element);
      playSong();
    }
  });


  window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please post a [mre]. If your question is about matching the words spoken, we don't need all the other code.

Comment: In your example you have `songs.some((element) =>`. Where is `songs` coming from?